# javascript - getting back a load functionality after sorting a table

Tags: javascript, sorting, html-table, highlighting

In the course 'Practical and Effective JavaScript' (Lynda.com), there's a table highlighting example and a table sorting example.

Here I added the sorting feature to the highlighting table example : 
http://aorbaroquethrash.com/07_tables/highlight_table.htm

It sorts.
The problem is that after sorting, I lost the highlighthing feature.

After sorting, the table is rebuild :

```
for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    oTBody.appendChild(theSortedRows[i]);
}
```

What could be done to keep the highlighting feature after sorting?

Comment: Why not do the style in a stylesheet? Also, how are the rows being sorted? the problem you're having makes it look like they're clones and not the original ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-bind the handlers which were a part of your table before. Looks like there is a method called `createAutoHiliteTableRows` inside `hiliteTables.js` which handles this.

```
for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    oTBody.appendChild(theSortedRows[i]);
}
createAutoHiliteTableRows(theSortedRows);
```